# Kendo grid column menu - last checked checkbox disabled

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Refering to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/jJnQF/) here , 
In the column menu, I am not able to select all columns. When only one more column is left checked, that column will be disabled. In my original production code, I excluded Id column by server side coding

```
.IncludeInMenu(false)
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you hide **all** columns from a grid ? It would become an empty box. Or I missed your point ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I omitted some columns in the column menu by IncludeInMenu(false) method. So they will be always shown